# Sortable Java collection without duplicates

Tags: java, sorting, collections, duplicates

I am searching for sortable (I mean sorting after initialization and many times using Comparator) Java class collection without duplicates. Is there any more pure solution than writing code which will opaque and prevent for example some ArrayList for adding another object with the same value that already exists?

Edit 1:
I should add some explanation about sorting. I need to sort this set of values many times with different comparators (diversity of implementations).

Answer (score 8):

Use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)! The common implementations are [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). The latter preserves the order of items as it implements [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html).

Comment: Glad you added SortedSet in there!

Comment: You can also use SortedMap ;)

Comment: @alfasin is a SortedMap a set?

Comment: A SortedMap is the interface. TreeMap is the implementation and it's a Map, not a Set (it has keys).

Comment: Indeed it's an interface and it's not a Set, it's a member of Java collections framework: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys :) But once I setted Comparator implementation during initialization TreeSet I can't then change it if  I understand it well.

Comment: You can't change the contents of the `compare` function at runtime without reflection perhaps, but you can store state information in the objects it is comparing to provide conditional logic.

Comment: @AramKocharyan
I am not sure I follow you. Do you mean to provide some sorting cases in one Comparator? I tried to do that, I wrote compare method with some flag and changing it from the outside has none effect.

`class Comparator{
...some final fields to provide many implementations from outside
...and one field keeping the chose + setter
compare(){if(field){dosmth}}`

Comment: The LinkedHashSet is often considered the best default implementation of a Set (see Effective Java). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Answer (score 6):

```
Set Interface---->SortedSet Interface----->TreeSet Class
Set Interface---->HashSet Class
Set Interface---->LinkedHashSet Class
```

You can Use `TreeSet`. It will remove duplicates.

`TreeSet` implements `SortedSet` Interface so that it will sort the elements entered

```
        SortedSet s=new TreeSet();
        s.add(12);
        s.add(12);
        s.add(1);
        s.add(56);
        s.add(6);
        s.add(47);
        s.add(1);
        System.out.println(s);
```

**Output**

```
[1, 6, 12, 47, 56]
```

Comment: You should mention the overhead of keeping the elements sorted the entire time.

Comment: @Woot4Foo To quote the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) "This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains)." That doesn't sound that bad.

Answer (score 1):

Use *Set* for unique elements.. You can always use *Collections.sort()* to sort any collection you use

Comment: The only implementations of sort method are providing sorting List elemenents:
`sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) 
sort(List<T> list)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

usage:

```
Collection collection = new HashSet();
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the stated question.

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to extend a standard collection or implement one from scratch. Eg:

```
class SetList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
  boolean add(E e) {
    if (contains(e)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      super.add(e);
      return true;
    }
  }

  void add(int index, E e) { .. }

  void addAll(..) {..}

  void addAll(..) {..}
}
```

And then you've got `Collections.sort` as previously stated. I would want to double-check everything though -- I can just imagine library methods making false assumptions about SetList because it extends ArrayList, leading to disaster. Read the javadocs of ArrayList, List, and Collection for a start, and really consider doing one from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Display each duplicate found and the sorted list without the names that are duplicates
public class NameSorter {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Sample array of names
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("Alice");
    names.add("Bob");
    names.add("Charlie");
    names.add("David");
    names.add("Alice"); // Duplicate entry
    names.add("Eve");
    names.add("Frank");
    names.add("Grace");
    names.add("Bob"); // Duplicate entry
    names.add("Hank");

    System.out.println("Original List: " + names);

    // Display each duplicate found and the sorted list without the names that are duplicates
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35567273)